# Look up tables and integer ranges - javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am looking to create look up tables. However I am running into a problem with integer ranges instead of just 1, 2, 3, etc. Here is what I have:

```
var ancient = 1;
var legendary = 19;
var epic = 251;
var rare = 1000;
var uncommon = 25000;
var common = 74629;
var poolTotal = ancient + legendary + epic + rare + uncommon + common;
var pool = general.rand(1, poolTotal);



 var lootPool = {
  1: function () {
      return console.log("Ancient");
     },
     2-19: function () {

      }
    };
```

Of course I know `2-19` isn't going to work, but I've tried other things like [2-19] etc etc.

Okay, so more information:
When I call: `lootPool[pool]();` It will select a integer between 1 and `poolTotal` Depending on if it is `1` it will log it in the console as ancient. If it hits in the range of `2 through 19` it would be legendary. So on and so forth following my numbers.

EDIT: I am well aware I can easily do this with a switch, but I would like to try it this way.

Comment: I don't mean any offense when I type this-- I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish.  This **might** indicate that either you need to provide more context in the body of your post, or that perhaps you are missing a tag that might provide more insight into the technology and goals.  Just my two cents-- perhaps I'm just slow on the uptake today.

Comment: Added more information... not sure if it helps you any though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than making a *huge* lookup table (which is quite possible, but very inelegant), I'd suggest making a (small) object, choosing a random number, and then finding the first entry in the object whose value is greater than the random number:

```js
// baseLootWeight: weights are proportional to each other
const baseLootWeight = {
  ancient: 1,
  legendary: 19,
  epic: 251,
  rare: 1000,
  uncommon: 25000,
  common: 74629,
};
let totalWeightSoFar = 0;
// lootWeight: weights are proportional to the total weight
const lootWeight = Object.entries(baseLootWeight).map(([rarity, weight]) => {
  totalWeightSoFar += weight;
  return { rarity, weight: totalWeightSoFar };
});
console.log(lootWeight);
const randomType = () => {
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalWeightSoFar);
  return lootWeight
    .find(({ rarity, weight }) => weight >= rand)
    .rarity;
};
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) console.log(randomType());
```

Comment: No idea what some of this stuff does, but it works and it is awesome, thank you! Although, now I'm going to have to figure out how to add functionality to it other than just sitting on the rarity name.

Comment: If I change `const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalWeightSoFar);` to `const rand = 20;` It prints out legendary. Shouldn't it print epic?

Comment: The `lootWeight` object's values represent the *cumulative* weight, one for which any random number equal to or higher corresponds to a rarity *at least as rare* as the one being considered. In contrast, baseLootWeight corresponds to the rarity *ratios*, compared to each other, which is a lot more intuitive. (eg `ancient` is 19 times less likely than `legendary`). A `rand` of 20 results in the `{ rarity: 'legendary', weight: 20 }` object being found because the initial `rand` is reserved for `ancient`.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a lookup, but this might help you.

```
let loots = {
    "Ancient": 1,
    "Epic": 251,
    "Legendary": 19
};

//We need loots sorted by value of lootType
function prepareSteps(loots) {
    let steps = Object.entries(loots).map((val) => {return {"lootType": val[0], "lootVal": val[1]}});
    steps.sort((a, b) => a.lootVal > b.lootVal);
    return steps;
}

function getMyLoot(steps, val) {
    let myLootRange;
    for (var i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
        if((i === 0 && val < steps[0].lootVal) || val === steps[i].lootVal) {
            myLootRange = steps[i];
            break;
        }
        else if( i + 1 < steps.length &&  val > steps[i].lootVal && val < steps[i + 1].lootVal) {
            myLootRange = steps[i + 1];
            break;
        }
    }
    myLootRange && myLootRange['lootType'] ? console.log(myLootRange['lootType']) : console.log('Off Upper Limit!');
}

let steps = prepareSteps(loots);
let pool = 0;
getMyLoot(steps, pool);
```